# How to view SOAP fault details from Bing Ads API failure

Tags: c#, bing-ads-api

I have a request I'm making to the Bing Ads API that looks like this:

```
var _campaignManagementService = new ServiceClient<ICampaignManagementService>(
    _authorizationData,
    apiEnvironment
);

var getCampaignRequest = new GetCampaignsByIdsRequest
{
    AccountId = <the-accountid-is-here>,
    CampaignIds = new List<long>() { <the-campaignid-is-here> }
};

var getCampaignResponse = (await _campaignManagementService.CallAsync((s, r) => s.GetCampaignsByIdsAsync(r), getCampaignRequest));
```

When I run this, an exception is thrown on the last line that reports:

> "Invalid client data. Check the SOAP fault details for more information."

Unfortunately, using the API, I'm not seeing the details of the actual response.  Is there a way to get at this info?  (Short of rewriting the whole thing without using the API?)

Comment: What's the *actual full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`? In WCF/SOAP calls errors result in `FaultException<>`s that contain the fault details.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Thanks to *Panagiotis Kanavos* I found the solution i think. This is for a different api (reporting) but it should look the same.

The exception has an `InnerException` that is of type `System.ServiceModel.FaultException<Microsoft.BingAds.V13.Reporting.AdApiFaultDetail>` or something similar. This has the `Detail` property with additional information:

[image]

**Original post**:

Can't seem to be able to easily inspect the SOAP request. But you can sniff the request with [Fiddler classic](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic) The classic version is free.

[image]